# Getting error while creating a GKE Auto pilot cluster with shared VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp, gke-networking

I have tried to create a GKE auto pilot cluster with a shared VPC private network, assigned all the necessary permission to the GKE project. But I got stuck with this error: *"Error waiting for creating GKE cluster: All cluster resources were brought up, but: only 0 nodes out of 1 have registered; cluster may be unhealthy."*

Any thoughts or references on how to overcome this exception while creating a GKE auto pilot cluster resource in gcp ?

[GKE Cluster error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKahc.png)

I have created a shared VPC subnets with the a private IP range, and tried to create a GKE auto pilot cluster with this shared VPC network with the necessary IAM roles as per the documentation. Got stuck with this error:Error waiting for creating GKE cluster: All cluster resources were brought up, but: only 0 nodes out of 1 have registered; cluster may be unhealthy. Any thoughts on overcome this error.

Comment: As you tagged the question with terraform, please include the code that you used.

Comment: This error is usually caused by a misconfigured service account used at cluster creation.  Check that the service account has the correct minimum permissions (e.g. `roles/container.nodeServiceAccount`)